# Count number of occurrences of a word across multiple sheets in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Is there a way to count the number of occurences of a word across multiple sheets?

for example i have the following data

```
Sheet1
ANIMALS
cat
cat
cat
dog
mouse
```

```
Sheet2
ANIMALS
cat
dog
dog
elephant
```

In sheet 3 i want this to appear

```
ANIMALS     COUNT
cat         4
dog         3
mouse       1
elephant    1
```

it should also be dynamic so when i add an entry in either sheet 1 and 2 it will appear in sheet 3

im using the following formula in sheet 3 but its not working as how i imagined it would be

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY({Sheet1!A2:A1000,Sheet2!A2:A1000},"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 != '' group by Col1 label Col1 'animals', count(Col2) 'Count'"))
```

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace `{Sheet1!A2:A1000,Sheet2!A2:A1000}` with `{Sheet1!A2:A1000;Sheet2!A2:A1000}`

So your formula becomes

```
=QUERY({Sheet1!A2:A1000;Sheet2!A2:A1000},"select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 != '' group by Col1 label Col1 'animals', count(Col1) 'Count'")
```

**Using `;` instead of `,` you stack one column on top of the other.**

[image]

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to accept. Glad I could help.